# JavaScript - What is the second item in the array on the ipfs.add() callback response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs

I have the following file uploaded to an [Express.js API](https://github.com/expressjs/express), using [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

```
[ { fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'file.pdf',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/pdf',
    destination: 'temp/',
    filename: 'b9e10b5ecce35483ff38c0e83b41a9f5',
    path: 'temp/b9e10b5ecce35483ff38c0e83b41a9f5',
    size: 456904 } ]
```

I passed it to the [IPFS](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs) protocol with the **ipfs.add()** using the following function

```
ipfs.add({
  path: listItem.path,
  content: fileBuffer,
}, (err, file) => {
  if (err) reject(err);
  console.log(file)
});
```

Which in the `console.log()` returns the following output

```
[ { path: 'temp/b9e10b5ecce35483ff38c0e83b41a9f5',
    hash: 'QmUNLLsPACC***',
    size: 4 },
  { path: 'temp',
    hash: 'QmfQjRQnQkV***',
    size: 82 } ]
```

My question is, why the second item appears if its supposed to be just adding the PDF file, and why it has my **temp** folder as a path, it is uploading all inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the automatically-created directory to hold the file.  The path you are passing has `temp/` at the start, so that directory is created.

Taken [directly from the documentation on `.add()`](https://github.com/ipfs/interface-js-ipfs-core/blob/master/SPEC/FILES.md#add):

> Note that intermediate directories in file paths will be automatically created and returned in the response along with files: